# Set Price of an NFT

Tags: anchor, solana-program, nft

Where do you save the price of a solana NFT? the metaplex metadata standard does not have a price field. I want to be able to store and fetch the price on my website

Comment: Was your question was to get live data of the price of an nft or collections of NFT and you want to show it on your site ?

Answer (score 3):

The Metaplex metadata standard has nothing to do with Price Field. If you want to charge your users with SOL or SPL Tokens like USDC or DUST then you have to include a system program Transfer ix in case of SOL here is the reference for SOL transfer [here](https://solanacookbook.com/references/basic-transactions.html#how-to-send-sol). If you want to charge SPL Tokens then you can refer to this [here](https://solanacookbook.com/references/basic-transactions.html#how-to-send-spl-tokens)

and regarding storing the price of the NFT you can either have it in a backend database or add it in the ENV of your front-end.

if this answer does not answer your question let me know I will revise it cause the question is a bit unclear to me and I answered it based on my understanding.

Comment: do nft market places store nft price on backend?

Comment: yes i think so for better performance

Answer (score 1):

Each NFT can be sold at any price in a marketplace. The price of the NFT is mentioned in the listing created for NFT's sale in the marketplace. This listing is an on-chain PDA account owned by the metaplex AuctionHouse program account.
You can create such a listing, using `createSellInstruction` function of Metaplex JS SDK (https://www.npmjs.com/package/@metaplex-foundation/mpl-auction-house).
Below are the input argument list for this function,

```
  export type SellInstructionArgs = {
  tradeStateBump: number;
  freeTradeStateBump: number;
  programAsSignerBump: number;
  buyerPrice: beet.bignum;
  tokenSize: beet.bignum;
};
```

BuyerPrice is the argument that stores the price of this NFT for this listing in the marketplace. And there can be multiple listings for a NFT as per this protocol.

Here is the source code file for this instruction:
https://github.com/metaplex-foundation/metaplex-program-library/blob/master/auction-house/js/src/generated/instructions/sell.ts

Answer (score 0):

I think It depends on how you created the nft, because nft's are minted throguh a smart contract and you need to know the structure of that smart contract. if it is created by candy machine,

```
const provider = getProvider();
const idl = await Program.fetchIdl(candyMachineProgram, provider);
// idl is like abi, program allows us directly interact with the candy machine
const program = new Program(idl, candyMachineProgram, provider);
const candyMachine = await program.account.candyMachine.fetch(
  CANDY_MACHINE_ID
);

console.log("candy machine", candyMachine);
```

this is the result of log

[image]

so you can access the price by `candyMachine.data.price`

- candy machine V2 is deprecated. newest cli is [sugar machine](https://docs.metaplex.com/tools/sugar/overview/)

You get an interactive setup with

```
 sugar launch
```

once you complete the setup, your new candy machine will be created and you will get the candy machine id

You get the price command, you enter the price.

```
 sugar show <CANDY MACHINE ID>
```

you will get an object including the price